# Unable to Generate Forest Plot in R 'metafor' package; Error "Number of outcomes does not correspond to the length of the 'slab' argument"

Tags: r, r-forestplot, metafor

I am estimating correlations between variables and outcome variables using 'metafor'. For each correlation estimate, I am trying to create forest plots. I successfully created three, though with every other estimate, using the exact same command, I encounter the error ' Number of outcomes does not correspond to the length of the 'slab' argument.'

After uploading my data, I proceed to convert my correlations to reduce bias;

```
dat <- escalc(measure="UCOR", ri=ri, ni=ni, data=data, vtype="UB")
```

The following is an example of my output;

```
                     Source      ri        sei     ni     yi     vi 
  1 Barker-Collo et al, 2010b   0.236  0.06085354  257  0.2364 0.0035 
  2    Campanholo et al, 2015   0.565  0.16181364  28   0.5728 0.0179 
  3    De Andrade et al, 2010   0.500  0.12500000  50   0.5040 0.0119 
  4       Jaywant et al, 2018   0.230  0.09830710  100  0.2311 0.0093 
  5     Jefferson et al, 2008   0.240  0.16179548  38   0.2433 0.0259 
  6       Jokinen et al, 2015   0.272  0.04769930  409  0.2723 0.0021 
  7      Marshall et al, 2011   0.170  0.05022288  387  0.1702 0.0025 
  8          Park et al, 2015   0.061  0.10134554  99   0.0613 0.0104
```

Perform my meta-analysis;

```
maModel <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat, method="HS")
summary(maModel)

Random-Effects Model (k = 8; tau^2 estimator: HS)

logLik  deviance       AIC       BIC      AICc 
4.0566   16.3487   -4.1131   -3.9542   -1.7131   

tau^2 (estimated amount of total heterogeneity): 0.0062 (SE = 0.0055)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):      0.0786
I^2 (total heterogeneity / total variability):   51.88%
H^2 (total variability / sampling variability):  2.08

Test for Heterogeneity:
Q(df = 7) = 17.5566, p-val = 0.0141

Model Results:

estimate     se    zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub 
0.2614     0.0411  6.3608  <.0001  0.1809  0.3420  *** 

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

And then attempt to generate a forest plot:

```
forest(maModel, slab=dat$source)
```

`source` is simply a combined title of author and year. 
This works for only 3 out of my 10 analyses.

As indicated, the error message I encounter is

> Error in forest.rma(maModel, slab = dat$source) : 
>   "Number of outcomes does not correspond to the length of the 'slab'
>   argument"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Without a reproducible example it is difficut for other users to assist you. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to refine your question.

Comment: Please, share the output of `dput(data)`.

Comment: Thank you! I hope the above works? I can also share the data that appears to work and generate a forest plot as expected, if you like?